# Luke 11:41 What is clean by giving alms?

Tags: greek, luke

> But rather give alms of such things as ye have; and, behold, **all
> things are clean** unto you. **(Luke 11:41 - KJV)**
>
> But give as alms those things that are within, and behold, **everything
> is clean** for you. **(Luke 11:41 - ESV)**

What exactly is clean by giving alms? all my deeds, my heart or is it all meat?

Comment: Just as water cleanses the hands of various physical impurities, so also almsgiving cleanses the soul of its spiritual impurities, mentioned just two verses earlier.

Answer (score 5):

Jesus was talking about more than outward giving of alms.  He was talking about giving from the heart.  Being clean on the inside makes the outside clean. Giving of yourself from within as if you were giving alms on the outside makes your actions clean as well as the inside.  The context:

> 37 While Jesus was speaking, a Pharisee asked him to dine with him, so he went in and reclined at table. 38 The Pharisee was astonished to see that he did not first wash before dinner. 39 And the Lord said to him, “Now you Pharisees cleanse the outside of the cup and of the dish, but inside you are full of greed and wickedness. 40 You fools! Did not he who made the outside make the inside also? 41 But give as alms those things that are within, and behold, everything is clean for you.
> 42 “But woe to you Pharisees! For you tithe mint and rue and every herb, and neglect justice and the love of God. These you ought to have done, without neglecting the others. 43 Woe to you Pharisees! For you love the best seat in the synagogues and greetings in the marketplaces. 44 Woe to you! For you are like unmarked graves, and people walk over them without knowing it.”
> (Luke 11:37–44, ESV)

Note what Jesus also said:

> A new commandment I give to you, that you love one another: just as I have loved you, you also are to love one another. 35 By this all people will know that you are my disciples, if you have love for one another.”
> (John 13:34–35, ESV)

> This is my commandment, that you love one another as I have loved you. 13 Greater love has no one than this, that someone lay down his life for his friends.
> (John 15:12–13, ESV)

> Jesus answered, “The most important is, ‘Hear, O Israel: The Lord our God, the Lord is one. 30 And you shall love the Lord your God with all your heart and with all your soul and with all your mind and with all your strength.’ 31 The second is this: ‘You shall love your neighbor as yourself.’ There is no other commandment greater than these.” 32 And the scribe said to him, “You are right, Teacher. You have truly said that he is one, and there is no other besides him. 33 And to love him with all the heart and with all the understanding and with all the strength, and to love one’s neighbor as oneself, is much more than all whole burnt offerings and sacrifices.” 34 And when Jesus saw that he answered wisely, he said to him, “You are not far from the kingdom of God.” And after that no one dared to ask him any more questions.
> (Mark 12:29–34, ESV)

Paul expressed it this way:

> Owe no one anything, except to love each other, for the one who loves another has fulfilled the law. 9 For the commandments, “You shall not commit adultery, You shall not murder, You shall not steal, You shall not covet,” and any other commandment, are summed up in this word: “You shall love your neighbor as yourself.” 10 Love does no wrong to a neighbor; therefore love is the fulfilling of the law.
> (Rom. 13:8–10, ESV)

**Appendix:** Commentaries

> 11:41. The Aramaic word for “cleanse” (Mt 23:26) is similar to that for “give in charity”; it is possible that Luke adopts one nuance of an Aramaic wordplay by Jesus, while Matthew adopts another.
> --
> Keener, C. S. (1993). The IVP Bible background commentary: New Testament (Lk 11:41). Downers Grove, IL: InterVarsity Press.

What is interesting the the amount of Aramaic play on words the Greek are contained within Luke's Gospel, although he was a Gentile.

> **Give as alms what is inside.** A difficult text in the original Greek. One possibility: “Give to the poor what is inside your cups and dishes,” here understood no longer as robbery and wickedness (v. 39) but food, good things in general. Another: “Give truly, from your heart,” i.e., from what is inside. A third: Luke, working from an Aramaic source, misread “zakki” (“give alms”) for “dakki” (“clean,” as in the parallel passage, Mt 23:26).
> --
> Stern, D. H. (1996). Jewish New Testament Commentary : a companion volume to the Jewish New Testament (electronic ed., Lk 11:41). Clarksville: Jewish New Testament Publications.

> **Howbeit** (πλην [plēn]). See Luke 6:24. Instead of devoting so much attention to the outside. **Those things which are within** (τα ἐνοντα [ta enonta]). Articular neuter plural participle from ἐνειμι [eneimi], to be in, common verb. This precise phrase only here in the N. T. though in the papyri, and it is not clear what it means. Probably, give as alms the things within the dishes, that is have inward righteousness with a brotherly spirit and the outward becomes “clean” (καθαρα [kathara]). Properly understood, this is not irony and is not Ebionism, but good Christianity (Plummer).
> --
> Robertson, A. T. (1933). Word Pictures in the New Testament (Lk 11:40). Nashville, TN: Broadman Press.

> One indication that they were clean on the inside would be their willingness to give material things to the poor. This meant not that their act of giving would atone for their sins, but that it would show a proper relationship to the Law and to God.
> --
> Martin, J. A. (1985). Luke. In J. F. Walvoord & R. B. Zuck (Eds.), The Bible Knowledge Commentary: An Exposition of the Scriptures (Vol. 2, p. 237). Wheaton, IL: Victor Books.

> 41. A very obscure verse, perhaps meaning that alms effect a true cleansing because they unite the affluent with the poor in one great human need for salvation.
>     --
>     Brown, R. E., Fitzmyer, J. A., & Murphy, R. E. (1996). The Jerome Biblical commentary (Vol. 2, p. 145). Englewood Cliffs, NJ: Prentice-Hall.

Comment: Thank you Perry +1 "Being clean on the inside makes the outside clean" Like a clean heart do no dirty deeds or clean heart purify dirty deeds?

Comment: A clean heart eliminates dirty deeds.

Comment: a similar vers that alms cleanses can be found in the book of Tobit; For almsgiving saves from death and purges away every sin. Those who give alms will enjoy a full life, Tobit 12:9 Sounds more like you pay off your sins "give as alms and behold everything is clean"

Answer (score 2):

Luke 11:41 What is clean by giving alms?

What exactly is clean by giving alms? all my deeds, my heart or is it all meat?

To understand Vs 41 it is necessary to read it in context, Jesus is rebuking the Pharisees and Experts in the Law. The Pharisees and others ritually wash their hands before the meal but do not cleanse their hearts from greed and wickedness. And so Jesus advises: 41 But give from your heart to those in need, and then everything will be clean for you.

"Giving from the heart", Jesus is referring to the qualities of the heart,  a good deed to be an act of true mercy, it must be a gift that comes from inside​, from a loving and willing heart. The parallel in Matthew 6:2  also reads "do not blow your trumpet",  figuratively meaning that one should not publicize their acts of charity--then everything will be clean for you.

Rebuking the Pharisees and Experts in the Law

> 37 As he spoke,[dj] a Pharisee[dk] invited Jesus[dl] to have a meal
> with him, so he went in and took his place at the table.[dm] 38
> The[dn] Pharisee was astonished when he saw that Jesus[do] did not
> first wash his hands[dp] before the meal. 39 But the Lord said to him,
> “Now you Pharisees clean the outside of the cup and the plate, but
> inside you are full of greed and wickedness.[dr] 40 You fools![ds]
> Didn’t the one who made the outside make the inside as well?[dt] 41
> But give from your heart to those in need,[du] and[dv] then everything
> will be clean for you.[dw]
>
> 42 “But woe to you Pharisees You give a tenth of your mint, rue,[ea]
> and every herb, yet you neglect justice and love for God! But you
> should have done these things without neglecting the others.

Comment: Thanks Ozzie for your answer +1 "do not blow your trumpet", figuratively meaning that one should not publicize their acts of charity" To put up a sign after digging a well like this https://ibb.co/hBWTWpV is that blowing trumpet?

Comment: Daniel Dahlberg;  Yes it is blowing the trumpet, I cannot imagine our Lord Jesus doing it.

Comment: Amen I felt that way to "But when thou dost alms, let not thy left hand know what thy right hand doth. That thy alms may be in secret, and thy Father who seeth in secret will repay thee." One could make a neutral sign that points to Christ alone but excludes the congregation "This well has been built by the good will of our Lord and Savior Jesus Christ" I wounder how many of that kind of signs there is in Africa..

Answer (score 2):

Mark 7:

> 14 Again Jesus called the crowd to him and said, “Listen to me, everyone, and understand this. 15Nothing outside a person can defile them by **going into** them. Rather, it is what **comes out** of a person that defiles them.”

Jesus contrasted going-into from coming-out of a person. He focused on the deeper reality of what was inside a person that came out of a person. In particular, he targeted the Pharisees,
Luke 11:

> 37 While Jesuse was speaking, a Pharisee asked him to dine with him, so he went in and reclined at table. 38The Pharisee was astonished to see that he did not first wash before dinner. 39And the Lord said to him, “Now you **Pharisees** cleanse the outside of the cup and of the dish, but inside you are full of greed and wickedness.

The Pharisees' focus was outside and not inside.

> 40 You fools! Did not he who made the outside make the inside also?

But the reality was that God controlled both sides and the inside was more important than the outside.

> 41 But give as alms those things that are within, and behold, everything is clean for you.

Jesus was saying: If these Pharisees would clean their hearts and let clean things come out, then they would not need to worry about washing their hands so much.

What is clean by giving alms?

If the Pharisees would clean their hearts and generously give good things to the poor from their hearts, then everything will be clean for them. Then they wouldn't need to worry about washing their hands so frequently because God would take care of them.

Jesus went one step further before he ascended, Mark 16:

> 18b
> when they drink deadly poison, it will not hurt them at all;

Comment: @ToncyChan Thank you Tony for your answer +1

Answer (score 1):

In the passage of the verse in question, the Pharisees question why Jesus did not wash before eating. Beyond just hygiene, this custom of washing held ceremonial and religious significance. Compare to the similar scenario involving Jesus’ disciples in Mark 7:1-5:

> Now when the Pharisees gathered to him, with some of the scribes who
> had come from Jerusalem, 2 they saw that some of his disciples ate
> with hands that were defiled, that is, unwashed. 3 (For the Pharisees
> and all the Jews do not eat unless they wash their hands properly,
> holding to the tradition of the elders, 4 and when they come from the
> marketplace, they do not eat unless they wash. And there are many
> other traditions that they observe, such as the washing of cups and
> pots and copper vessels and dining couches.) 5 And the Pharisees and
> the scribes asked him, “Why do your disciples not walk according to
> the tradition of the elders, but eat with defiled hands?”

In both instances Jesus challenges the Pharisees’ notion of defilement while juxtaposing two sets of opposing concepts: inside vs. outside and clean vs. unclean.

> There is nothing outside a person that by going into him can defile
> him, but the things that come out of a person are what defile him. –
> Mark 7:14
>
> And the Lord said to him, “Now you Pharisees cleanse the outside of
> the cup and of the dish, but inside you are full of greed and
> wickedness. – Luke 11:41

Jesus points out the irony that though the Pharisees kept the outward appearance of cleanliness through the customs of washing and purification, they were inwardly full of impurity.  If “greed and wickedness” make a person unclean, it follows that their antithetical counterparts, such things as charity and goodness, are what marks a person as clean. By this logic, giving “as alms those things that are within” then refers to the sharing of such intangible treasures as kindness, compassion, forgiveness and mercy. These things flow from and testify to the purity of what lies within.

“And behold, everything is clean for you.” The implication is that if the inside is clean, then the outside, indeed everything else, will be clean as well. In other words, when the inside of a person is pure, then their external actions, whether they be acts of charity or religious rites and practices, will be pure as well. The cleaning of the cup and the dish is an external act of purification that is pointless because it neither reflects nor effects a genuine inner cleansing.

> From the Meyer’s NT Commentary
>
> Luke 11:41. A prescription how they are to effect the true
> purification. Πλήν is verumtamen (see on Luke 6:24): Still, in order
> to set aside this foolish incongruity, give that which is therein (the
> contents of your cups and platters) as alms, and behold everything is
> pure unto you … this loving activity will then make your entire
> ceremonial purifications superfluous for you.

To my mind Jesus’ words reinforce one of the most important themes of Scripture: that true religion does not lie in superficial acts of piety and purification, but in inner transformation and sanctification.

> For I desire steadfast love and not sacrifice,
> the knowledge of God rather than burnt offerings. – Hosea 6:6

We are the cup and the dish that God created to become, as Paul the apostle so aptly words it, “vessels of mercy” (Rom 9:23). This is the will of God for us, and it is in the daily effort to fulfill it that we come closer to meeting God’s standards of purity.

> And everyone who thus hopes in him purifies himself as he is pure. – 1
> John 3:3

Answer (score 1):

The thing that is given is the inner things of yourself - your desires, your hopes, your doctrines, your inner man. If you are willing to give these up in service to God and to the community, then you will be cleansed. And how are you to give? As if you were giving an alm. Specifically, alms are to be given:

- in service to God
- generously
- cheerfully
- in a way that costs you (you are to give something dearly) not give something that is not important to you.

In the same way, if you give of the inner things within yourself in service to God, generously, cheerfuly, and in a way that costs you - then you will be cleansed.  Thus this is a restatement of the idea of abandoning yourself, or taking no thought for yourself, and offering yourself as a living sacrifice to God, where it is understood that God is not interested in your physical strength or your money, but in your heart, in your *inward self*. That is what must be given as an appropriate alm or sacrifice to God.